# Angular, how to initialize and access the child object array of a class instance

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass an object from an array of objects which is a child for another parent object, as input to a child component.

```
Data object 
export class CallauditHeaderClass {
   //more fields here..

    CallAuditDetails: CallauditDetailClass[];
}

Component Class:

constructor(){
   this.currentcallaudit = new CallauditHeaderClass();
}

ngOnInit() {

this.getCallAuditTypes();
 this.currentcallaudit.CallAuditDetails = [];
for (let callaudittype of this.callaudittypes) {

  let tmpcallauditdetail: CallauditDetailClass;
  tmpcallauditdetail = new CallauditDetailClass();       
  tmpcallauditdetail.CallAuditTypeId = callaudittype.CallAuditTypeId;
  tmpcallauditdetail.CallAuditTypeCode = callaudittype.CallAuditTypeCode;
  console.log(tmpcallauditdetail);
  this.currentcallaudit.CallAuditDetails.push(tmpcallauditdetail);
 }   

}

getCallAuditDetailForAuditType(CallAuditTypeCode: string)
 {
    return this.currentcallaudit.CallAuditDetails.find(calldetail => 
     calldetail.CallAuditTypeCode==CallAuditTypeCode);
  }  

 HTML:

 <app-callaudit-detail   
    [callauditdetail]= "getCallAuditDetailForAuditType 
     (callaudittype.CallAuditTypeCode)">
</app-callaudit-detail>
```

I am trying to display currentcallaudit object in JSON format on the UI, But the object is not initialized. Please advise how to get this working.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `filter` was only a included pipe in AngularJS, NOT Angular. You'll have to write your own pipe or check NPM.

Comment: I'd also recommend brushing up on angular proprty binding syntax so that you don't need to use {{ }} everywhere https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-

Comment: Thanks user184994. I did refined my property bindings and now calling a component class method to find my object and my question is still open